# PHP databases - don't want to show javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, css, database

I have problem with PHP and JavaScript/CSS.

I have database with table. The table has a descriptions of articles. I want to echo the descriptions of the articles from database. Unfortunately many of them has a JavaScript or CSS included ( Then some article text), so when I use echo, it shows all of that code (and after that text). Is there any way to not show the JavaScript/CSS part and show only the text? For example with str_replace and regular expression? If yes, can somebody write me how it should look like?

Thanks for help and let me know if u need more info (code etc.)

Comment: There isn't. You can obfuscate your CSS and JS, but if someone wants it, they'll get it (it also takes 10 seconds to "crack" the usual obfuscation techniques). Just give up on hiding your css / js.

Comment: Could you please clarify: Do you want to remove the scripts and styling, or just hide their code?

Comment: Please read about Cross Site Scripting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) - storing user-entered javascript in your database and then showing it to random visitors is almost certainly a huge security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following regex to remove the script and css:

```
"<script[\d\D]*?>[\d\D]*?</script>"
"<style[\d\D]*?>[\d\D]*?</style>"
```

It should help, but it cannot remove all the scripts. Like onclick="javascript:alert(1)".

Comment: I have simply question :) How to make PHP to not read the ?> as a closing tag? Becouse I cant use that code what u gave me

Comment: You can try this:
"&lt;script[\d\D]*?&gt;[\d\D]*?&lt;/script&gt;"
"&lt;style[\d\D]*?&gt;[\d\D]*?&lt;/style&gt;"

Answer (score 5):

Use [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) - it will remove the scripts, css and any harmfull content from your articles. Since it is a CPU-intensive operations, it's better to run article trough HTMLPurifer before saving in the database, then to run it each time you are showing the article.

Comment: This is the best way to go about this if I'm reading the situation right. You may also want to display a short message to your users to NOT enter any CSS, HTML or Javascript tags when saving their articles, assuming this is a blog-like structure and your users are creating this content with CSS/JS included? If you want/need the JS included and you have control over it I don't recommend it, but you can't remove it from output without removing the functionality.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to remove tags from a user's post, you can call `strip_tags`. This will get rid of css links, script tags, etc. It will not get rid of the `style` attribute, but if you get rid of `div`, `span`, `p`, etc. that won't matter -- there will be no tag for it to reside on.

As has been stated by others, it is generally best to sanitize your *input* (data from user before it goes into the DB), than it is to sanitize your *output*.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to simply hide the JS and CSS from users, you can use Packer to obfusicate Javascript from less-savvy users, use [Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) and use base 62 encoding. The JS will still work but will look like jiberish. Be aware that more knowledgeable users can attempt to unobfusicate the code, so any critical security risks in the JS still exists. Don't think any JS that accesses your databases directly will be safe; instead remove database access from the Javascript for security. If the JS is just to do fancy things like move elements around the page it's probably fine to just obfuscate it.

Only consider this if YOU have complete control and awareness of all JS included with the articles. If this is something your anonmous or otherwise not 120% trusted users can upload, you need to kill that functionality and use HTML Purifier to remove any JS they might add. It is not safe to output user entered JS, for you or your users.

For the CSS, I'm not sure why you want to hide it, and CSS can't be obfuscated quite like JS can; the styles will still be in plain English, best you can do is butcher the class/id names and whitespace; outputting CSS that YOU generated isn't a real security risk though, and even if people reverse engineer it I wouldn't be that afraid.

Again, if this is something anonymous/non trusted users can ADD to your site on their own, you don't want this at all, so remove the ability to upload CSS with an article using the HTML Purifier Darhazer mentioned.